# Invalid Transactions - Do those make a node bad?

Tags: iri-node, transaction, node, neighbors

I'm working on a application to track your neighbors. I want an indicator if there are any foul nodes.

What's the deal with invalid transactions? They are an indicator that a node is bad, but how many invalid transactions would a node need for you to remove it as neighbor?

Do good nodes never have invalid transactions?

If it is just an indicator and not a "1 invalid transactions = bad node!", then I would probably weight them up against the new transactions, or all transactions (ideas are welcome). Say: "If 0.5% or more of all transactions are invalid, the node should be removed."

Comment: As far as I have seen, invalid transactions are usually caused by the other node running an older iri version with laxer transaction checking. And in this case, there is a high chance that once you see one of them, you will see a lot of them. Removing the node might reduce your network load, but only if the other node will remove you too. Seeing invalid transactions from a node with same version as yours means either a malicious node or the node has some trouble with his database. Talk to their owners and if it does not help, probably remove them.